# Is simple action client deprecated?

Tags: ros-groovy, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Groovy (Ubuntu Precise) I get a depreciated warning when I compile my code with the simple_action_client.h included. I get this message:

```
/opt/ros/groovy/include/actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h:51:0: warning: "DEPRECATED" redefined [enabled by default]
/opt/ros/groovy/include/octomap/octomap_deprecated.h:7:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
```

In that file I find:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#define DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
#else
#define DEPRECATED
#endif
```

Why is simple_action_client.h depreciated? And should I switch to just action_client.h?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53408/is-simple-action-client-deprecated?/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2013-01-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, `SimpleActionClient` is **NOT** deprecated.

What you are seeing is a warning about re-defining the macro used to annotate a given function or class is deprecated. It looks like `octomap` is also defining a macro to use to deprecate code, and they are both called `DEPRECATED`.

Second, you can see [here](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap/blob/devel/octomap/include/octomap/octomap_deprecated.h#L38) that the version in `octomap` checks if `DEPRECATED` is already defined. The version in `simple_action_client.h` should also define it in this way.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-01-26**:
thanks. i tried to submit a bug report or patch myself just now, but had issues with the old Trac system. i can't wait for everyone to be on github. i emailed one of the maintainers, maybe they can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I submitted a [patch](https://gist.github.com/davetcoleman/4961194) to Dirk for ActionLib to fix this depreciated warning.

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2013-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-02-15**:
Patch applied.